# Unable to connect to django server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin, server

I have installed django successfully in my ubuntu machine. i also run `python manage.py runsurver` successfully according to the tutorial 
but when i am trying to access server from browser at `http://127.0.0.1:8000` i am getting error like this

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.
```

it was supposed to give a welcome message

Comment: Do you get any error in your console when you run the server? Module missing or something?

Comment: no it works exactly as tutorials says

Comment: Does the console give you an IP/port that the server is running through? The console usually says something along the lines of `running at XXX.X.X.X:XXX`

Comment: What do you get on **0.0.0.0:8000**?

Comment: Do you use proxy? If yes then turn it of for 127.0.0.1.

Comment: it tells that development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: but it is supposed to print 'welcome to django' but it just prints "It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

"

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

instead of:

```
python manage.py runsurver
```